# piping with make dosen't work

Tags: linux, gnu-make

I'm quite new to make, and I tried to create a phony target to print targets:

```
.PHONY: help
help:
        $(MAKE) --print-data-base --question | \
        $(AWK) '/^[^.%][-A-Za-z0-9_]*:/ { print substr($$1, 1, length($$1)-1) }' | \
        $(SORT) | \
        $(PR) --omit-pagination --width=80 --columns=4
```

the code is taken from [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/make3/book/ch02.pdf) (page 20).

when I run `make help` I get the following:

```
make --print-data-base --question | \
     '/^[^.%][-A-Za-z0-9_]*:/ { print substr($1, 1, length($1)-1) }' | \
     | \
     --omit-pagination --width=80 --columns=4
/bin/sh: 3: Syntax error: "|" unexpected
make: *** [help] Error 2
```

what's wrong and how can I fix it?

I'm working on linux mint, make 3.81 built for i686-pc-linux-gnu.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `$(AWK)`, `$(SORT)`, and `$(PR)` are all expanding to the empty string, which means no such variables are defined in your makefile.

Comment: Yes, and always run make with `--warn` to catch these (all to frequent) errors.

Comment: Can the snippet be modified to use awk, sort, pr directly?